# Auto-generated code CRUD statements WCF

Tags: database, winforms, wcf, auto-generate

I'm a begginer in WCF. I would like to do a Windows Forms application using WCF service that get some data from a database.

CRUD operations and statements could be **auto-generated code** rings a bell.

Could anyone help me or tell me how to do it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you explain better (and give some reference) about what do you mean with _auto-generated code_?

Comment: Something like that:
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/accessing-the-database-directly-from-an-aspnet-page/inserting-updating-and-deleting-data-with-the-sqldatasource-cs

Step2. But I'd like to do it in with WindForms and WCF.